Regular expression to identify CSS functions
I have a variable called $value that contains a string with a css expression. It can be a value or a function:
rgb( 25, 128, 128 );, transform( -50% -50% );, bottom 50px right 100px;, #198080;, bold;, 1px solid red;
I want to be able to identify if the expression contains a function or a string
$real_value = (is_numeric($value)) ?
    $value :
    (is_string($value) ?
        (preg_match('/^\w/', $value) ? $value : '"' . $value . '"') :
        '"'. $value . '"');

The idea is to assign to $real_value the value inside quotation marks like this: "#198080"; or this "bottom 50px right 100px"; but if it is a function, just return the same expression.
I started creating my regular expression, but I can't go past the first parentheses without breaking it: /^\w\-?\w?\(/
So I need to create a regular expression that checks if the string has the structure of a css function. There are not many of them (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_functions.php) or just write one that checks for the parentheses

You might want to use some kind of a CSS parser rather than a regex.

To check for a structure of those css functions \b(?:attr|calc|conic-gradient|counter|cubic-bezier|hsla?|max|min|(?:(?:linear|radial)|repeating-(?:conic|linear|radial))-gradient|rgba?|var)\([^()]*\);?  and then extend the list if needed https://regex101.com/r/OER19M/1

@the are you supplying resolving advice as a comment?

“or just write one that checks for the parentheses” - this one seems the simpler and more future proof, and you can just use str_contains. There’s definitely exceptions, for instance with the content property, but those would then start with a quote of some sort.
